# Call a class function in a self in another function so that the attributes only include one and the variable not included but is self function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is in the main function:

Player and Computer are lists in this format:

```
player = ["name", 10, 20, 30]
```

10 is the health, 20 is the strength, and 30 is the dexterity

```
# Get the character for the user and the computer.
player = character_choices.get_and_remove_character(choice)
computer = character_choices.get_random_character()

# Preparation for the battle
print ("You have picked a " + player.name)
print ("The computer picked " + computer.name)
print ("Let's battle!\n")

# Battle Loop
rnd = 1
while (player.hit_points > 0 and computer.hit_points > 0):
    print ("Round: " + str(rnd))
    player.attack (computer)
    computer.attack (player)
```

This is the function:

```
def attack (self, enemy):
    self.player = [self]
    if self.player[3] == enemy[3]:
```

I do not know how to call the player variable within the attack function in this format I can not change the attributes and I do not know how to get the player list items to compare to the enemies list items and fight.

Comment: You're using `self` in your `attack` function, `self` is a convention for classes. Can you confirm this is your full (if not, minimalised) code? No hidden classes anywhere?

Comment: The attack is in a class called Character(object) this is minimalized code just for the attack part where two characters attack each other

Comment: @GaryZlobinskiy You should post your `Character` class for better clarity

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. You need to provide more details about your code and what exactly it is you want to accomplish. If `player` were indeed a list, `player.hit_points` would give you an attribute error.

Comment: Hi @GaryZlobinskiy . For reference, please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve] and reform your question with those in mind in order to maximise your chances of getting a *precise* and *accurate* answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self is a variable commonly related to objects in python by convention.
In your case, to make use of self, you should read up on python object oriented programming.
https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Go through the tutorial in the link and once you are done, you will have a better understanding of what you want to achieve using your code. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you but i understand classes it is just in this situation I dod not know what to do

Comment: @GaryZlobinskiy In this case, if you want to make use of `self`, you should input the data contained in your `list` into a `class` defined by you. 
Or are you asking for code that simply modifies the lists as provided by your question? Because your lists do not contain attributes such as `player.hit_points` and the functions `player.attack` and `computer.attack` also do not exist. They indicate you are trying to do it via `object` oriented programming